# Button behaves as Drop down

Tags: acumatica

I have created a button named Get Activities and when the customization is published this button sometimes behaves as a drop-down with one option getactivities in it.Not sure why it is behaving so. Below is the code for the button.

```
    public PXAction<CRCase> getActivities;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Get Activities", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable GetActivities(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
       ....
        return adapter.Get();

    }
```

ASPX code:

```
    <px:PXToolBarButton Text="Get Activities">
    <AutoCallBack Command="GetActivities" Target="ds" /></px:PXToolBarButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with singular name of the command instead of plural. So in your case change command name `GetActivities` to `GetActivity` in your code and aspx both.